# How do I prevent my Django Database from being overwritten

Tags: django, django-models

Currently I have a Django application running on my personal website from PythonAnywhere.com. When I make updates to the site I login to PythonAnywhere and git pull to update my application. When I do this the data that was entered through the website since the last update gets lost from the database when I update. What can I do to overcome this?

I am currently using the SqlLite version that comes preinstalled with the Django App. This likely could be part of the issue but need some help understanding how to overcome it.

Answer (score 1):

I presume that your Django project is connecting to the SQLite database that gets generated when you create a new project and you are pushing that database in your deployment. That database won't be suitable for production and won't retain your changes, you instead need to setup a database that your application can connect to.

Here is some information on PythonAnywhere about databases:

https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/KindsOfDatabases/

And the Django documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/databases/